# Something New(ton)?

Tags: cipher, story, visual, steganography, history

Recognized as one of the most brilliant scientists of all time, Sir Isaac Newton was always ahead of his time.
On the cusp of something brilliant, late in 1704, he had the idea to send you a coded question.
You might wonder how Newton could send you a message 300-plus years into the future?
Good question.
But let me explain: he was a genius.
I cannot give you all the details, but I can point you in the right direction.
Verified for me, by a Newton scholar, I present to you the coded question Newton intended for you to answer.

P.S. - Oh good, I did not inhibit. Ever get near a rabid otter?

[image]

Checksum thing:  6F,35,09,43,04,0D,5D,55,5D,07,04,3D,0F,04,2D,67,04,66,3E,06,47,15,17,7A

---

**Cryptic Clue:**
An encoding scheme is a container ends like a yellow bird

**Hint:**

> Edited the introductory paragraph to put the starting point out in the open though I doubt that's what is holding someone back.

**Bigger Hint:**

> Newton holds the key once you've converted his color bar message to the correct format.  PS - Don't forget.

**One More:**

> Newton had to take a bite a bit smaller than you normally might. It seems it was a little tight to try and transmit it through the light.

Comment: Just an observation: the color pattern on the chair does not quite match the color pattern on the bottom. On the chair the spectrum goes from red to blue, via yellow, whereas on the bottom the spectrum goes from yellow to blue, via red.

Comment: To be clear, the "checksum" and the color pattern at the bottom are the same data. I was hoping the colors would retain the data necessary for the problem, but was pretty sure they wouldn't.

Comment: I have compared this image with the original engraving, and the only alteration I could find is that the order of the colors in the projection from the prism have been altered, from ROYGBV to BGVOYR (top to bottom). You can see the original engraving here: https://fashionfilmfrancais.files.wordpress.com/2015/11/newton-prism-experiment-2.jpg

Comment: Though this is my debut puzzle here, you should know that I attempt to keep themes tight even if my execution isn't perfect, and that any text I write usually has a very simple entry point to get the puzzle started. This puzzle is no exception.

Comment: Just in case it could possibly be helpful, the RGB values represent the string "o5C]U]=-gf>Gz" if using ASCII encoding (omitting the values that represent control codes).

Comment: @wildBillMunson Now can you apply the rest of the information from the entire puzzle?

Comment: Just have to ask. By 'a container ends with a yellow bird' do you mean CANary?

Comment: @wildBillMunson you're close there, but I'd only needed to have said yellow bird to get you to canary, right? And canary doesn't feel helpful.

Comment: I just started a bounty on this question so hopefully that attracts more attention and someone will be able to solve it. I'm held in suspense awaiting the solution!

Comment: The 1st char of each line is roygbiv

Comment: I think it might be time for another hint...

Comment: @wildBillMunson what's the answer to the cryptic clue?

Comment: I started a bounty on this question with the hopes that someone else could figure that out. But alas, no luck. I've no idea at this point...

Comment: container is a "bin". the end of a yellow bird is "ary".  If this isn't solved tomorrow, Newton will send another message to help.

Comment: The clue should have been "An encoding scheme is a container ends the same as a yellow bird" since "ary" isn't itself a yellow bird.

Comment: Beautiful feedback. I had just learned of those clues the day I wrote it. Thank you!

Comment: The hex values converted to binary is 0110 1111 0011 0101 0000 1001 0100 0011 0000 0100 0000 1101 0101 1101 0101 0101 0101 1101 0000 0111 0000 0100 0011 1101 0000 1111 0000 0100 0010 1101 0110 0111 0000 0100 0110 0110 0011 1110 0000 0110 0100 0111 0001 0101 0001 0111 0111 1010. Are you suggesting the answer is to be found here?

Comment: I believe everything needed has now been noted.

Comment: The first letters of "Oh good, I did not inhibit. Ever get near a rabid otter?" are OGIDNI EGNARO, which backwards is ORANGE INDIGO

Comment: Maybe we need to break the binary down into bytes with 7 bits each (a 'bit' smaller than 8 bit)? "Newton had to take a bite a bit smaller than you normally might. It seems it was a little tight to try and transmit it through the light."

Comment: ASCII encoding is 7-bit encoding from 0000 0000 - 0111 1111. Uppercase letters run from 0100 0001 - 0101 1010 and lowercase runs from 0110 0001 - 0111 1010. The first bit is always 0.

Comment: Whoa whoa wow !

Comment: Does the encoded question, by chance, ask for the name of a color?

Comment: @wildBillMunson are you writing up the solution? It sure does!

Comment: I'm getting close. Trying to reverse engineer the process from original to final binary and am getting close but not there yet.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The question Newton is asking is

> What color is at 490 THz?

And the the answer is

> Orange

I arrived at this answer by applying the following rules to transform the binary for each hex color value:

> 1) The first digit is always zero.  2) The eighth digit becomes the second.  3) The third digit is always one.  4) The seventh digit becomes the fourth.  5) The fourth digit becomes the fifth.  6) The second digit becomes the sixth.  7) The third digit becomes the seventh, in reverse order from top to bottom.  8) The fifth digit becomes the eighth.  This transformation scheme was derived from the transformation from ROYGBIV -> BIGVOYR (comparing the original illustration to the one included in this puzzle). Apply ASCII encoding to the new binary stream to produce the final text.

Here's a screenshot of the transformation:

> [image: transformation screenshot]

Comment: PS - you're almost there.

Comment: Do I simply have to figure out which one it is (490 or 690) or is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: .gnihtemos gnissim er'uoY

Comment: Got it! the 2nd digit goes to the 7th, upside down! Makes sense since orange and indigo are complementary colors of light! Editing now...

Comment: I had some errors in the my first try. I think I've fixed them now.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the transformation scheme. Is there a way to hide an image as a spoiler??

Comment: @wildBillMunson Just put it in >! like usual

Comment: Tried that and it doesn't work. It's okay. If someone doesn't want to see that, they can simply not scroll down to it. :D

Comment: Bill or @jim could one of you explain the mapping? Aside from `8>2`, `7>4`, and `2>6` the rest of the permutation makes no sense at all to me!

Comment: @Will thanks for getting the image working as a spoiler! :) Does the OP's explanation below suffice??

Comment: No problem! Yup, with OP's answer below (+ some assistance in chat) I now understand the full process. :)

Comment: I added color to the screenshot to make it more clear

Comment: That was indeed a smart clue. I feel dumb now ;) Great solve!!

Answer (score 4):

Partial Attempt. Hope it helps others working on this one...

**Findings**

> Taking first letter of each line of the first paragraph gives - **ROYGBIV**    
>  
>  **R**ecognized as one of the most brilliant scientists of all time, Sir Isaac Newton was always ahead of his time.
>  **O**n the cusp of something brilliant, late in 1704, he had the idea to send you a coded question.
>  **Y**ou might wonder how Newton could send you a message 300-plus years into the future?
>  **G**ood question.
>  **B**ut let me explain: he was a genius.
>  **I** cannot give you all the details, but I can point you in the right direction.
>  **V**erified for me, by a Newton scholar, I present to you the coded question Newton intended for you to answer.
>      
>  Taking the first letters of the P.S gives - reversed **ORANGE INDIGO**
>  **O**h **g**ood, **I** **d**id **n**ot **i**nhibit. **E**ver **g**et **n**ear **a** **r**abid **o**tter?

**Cryptic Clue:**

> An encoding scheme is a container ends like a yellow bird - Container(Bin) ends like a yellow bird(canary-ARY) gives - > **BINARY**  
>  So, this may indicate that the hex codes need to be translated to binary. And then may be binary to decimal which will reveal the letters to be used.

Hence,

> We need to take the Hex string and convert it into binary. 
>  Doing it, we get     
>  6F - 1101111
>  35 - 0110101
>  09 - 0001001
>  43 - 1000011
>  04 - 0000100
>  0D - 0001101
>  5D - 1011101
>  55 - 1010101
>  5D - 1011101
>  07 - 0000111
>  04 - 0000100
>  3D - 0111101
>  0F - 0001111
>  04 - 0000100
>  2D - 0101101
>  67 - 1100111
>  04 - 0000100
>  66 - 1100110
>  3E - 0111110
>  06 - 0000110
>  47 - 1000111
>  15 - 0010101
>  17 - 0010111
>  7A - 1111010

So, going with the hint we get -

> Removing one bit from the start i.e. 0 we get ->
>  6F - 01101111 -> o
>  35 - 00110101 -> 5
>  09 - 00001001
>  43 - 01000011 -> C
>  04 - 00000100
>  0D - 00001101
>  5D - 01011101 -> ]
>  55 - 01010101 -> U
>  5D - 01011101 -> ]
>  07 - 00000111
>  04 - 00000100
>  3D - 00111101 -> =
>  0F - 00001111
>  04 - 00000100
>  2D - 00101101 -> -
>  67 - 01100111 -> g
>  04 - 00000100
>  66 - 01100110 -> f
>  3E - 00111110 -> >
>  06 - 00000110
>  47 - 01000111 -> G
>  15 - 00010101
>  17 - 00010111
>  7A - 01111010 -> z

Hence we get ->

> **o5C]U]=-gf>Gz** This might be an encrypted text which needs to be decoded using the key as NEWTON. Or may be the colors have something to do with this.

Comment: Thanks. You've confirmed our previous findings (found in the notes under the main post). Good to organize them as a partial answer - more effective for other solvers!

Comment: Yeah. I was along with the notes all the way and thought why not convert the data into information. :) As for the final part, I am thinking it could be some sort of encryption may be DES or any typical one. I have been brute forcing it since days now and haven't been able to come anywhere close to decoding it. Hope with the stuff organized now, people can quickly get the solution.

Comment: It's a hand cipher. Bring down your difficulty level and don't forget the visual tag.

Comment: @Jim Ahh, an imgur image probably? Hmm

Comment: Newton holds the key.

Comment: Yeah. I tried vignere with Prism and Disc but no luck. May be I am doing something wrong.

Comment: I think the key is the color order (`BGVIOYR`). I've tried using it to permute the bits and although I get a fully\* printable ASCII string, it's still nonsense. (\* = Except for the final character which is `\x1F` - just outside the printable range)

Comment: @Will Once I am back on the machine, I am going to try substitution/transportation which are simplest ciphers. If you want you can go ahead and try it out.

Comment: This is one of those puzzles where now all I can do is sit back and wait.

Comment: I've tried XORing (with xortool-xor) the encrypted message with various keys (BGVOYRI, etc) but with no success.

Comment: Well I took it as far as I could and posted the best answer I could muster. This is a great puzzle! :)

Comment: @Techidiot since I can't award my own bounty to myself, I went ahead and awarded it to you, since your partial answer helped pave the way to my ultimately solving this puzzle. I'm still relatively new here..I hope that it is okay to do that! :)

Comment: @wildBillMunson That's generous! Thanks. And a great solve! :)

Answer (score 1):

## Not an answer, but  a wrap-up from the OP

Here's my explanation for the entire puzzle:

> I first envisioned this puzzle a couple years ago, but didn't really have a place to post it, until I stumbled upon this section of SE. 
>  
>
>  The idea was that Sir Isaac Newton would send you a message through his optics experiment, but when passing 7-bit binary through the prism, he could have various columnar transpositions of the encryption space. 
>  
>
>  To add to the challenge, I didn't simply want to create a columnar transposition, but also alter two of the "channels" of the transmission. 
>  
>
>  Newton "held" the key to the transposition arrangement (ROYGBIV -> BIGVOYR). Since I wasn't sure anyone would interpret Indigo as a color I made sure to reference his 1704 work (Opticks), as well as started each sentence with the letters ROYGBIV to define the transposition space. 
>  To reinforce the fact that the transmission took place through the 7 colors, I also explicitly used INDIGO in one of the twists found in the odd-reading PS - along with ORANGE. 
>  
>
>  From the encryption standpoint, I took the 7-bit binary encoding, and transposed it according to my key (BIGVOYR), and then also reversed the ORANGE and INDIGO bit streams before re-interpreting the output on the other side of the prism as a stream of colors. The checksum was added both to clarify which colors were in play and thus their binary interpretations. It also served to show that groups of two hex values would be used together.

Comment: This is a great puzzle! Thanks for posting it!!

Comment: That was a smart one!!